# How to figure out unspecified Japan Railway connection?

Tags: trains, jr-passes

We recently booked a number of seats on Japan Railway trains and there were a few odd ones with information missing. In particular all the departure info from the connection train is missing: Departure time, train name, train number.

**How do we figure out what to do when getting off the from first segment?**

Here we can see that the initial segment from Tokyo to Atami is fully specified. We know the arrival time in Atami and even in Ito but it does not say when the train leaves Atami.

[image]

Comment: Where was this booking made? Online? In person? Did you make the booking yourself?

Comment: On the [Japan Railway website](https://www.japanrailpass-reservation.net). This one looked official, so hopefully it's the real one but there seems to be many.

Comment: No idea why some didn't like the question. I made 8 bookings and only one had no departure time for the second train, so it's an anomaly that is worth understanding. One other reservation had a different oddity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using https://world.jorudan.co.jp/ for rail pass planning. They also have an app that works quite well. In this case you would get the full info like this

[image]

It also shows a different routing with a shorter connection, you can take your pick.

[image]

Comment: +1, but the Saphir Odoriko in your second option is a reservation-required luxury limited express, OP will not be able to use it with a regular JR ticket/pass.

Comment: It did show up in a rail-pass only search. Apparently it's free until Ito but not onwards: https://www.jrpass.com/forum/using-the-japan-rail-pass/posts/jr-pass-and-saphir-odoriko. Maybe it requires a Green Car pass ?

Comment: Interesting.  This blog says it's free uo to Ito if and only if you have a Green Car JR pass, but fees apply if you have a regular pass or go beyond Ito: https://www.jrpass.com/blog/the-saphir-odoriko-luxury-excursion-train-from-tokyo-to-izu-peninsula#Ticket%20and%20using%20the%20JR%20Pass%20on%20the%20Saphir%20Odoriko

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [outbound timetable](https://www.izukyu.co.jp/global_site/pdf/outbound_e20181001.pdf) (PDF)  I think that the train matching your schedule departs Atami about 12:24.

[image]

If you look at the line above the highlighted section, you can see that the previous train arrives at 12:11, which seems to match your itinerary.  Which means you have about 15 minutes to enjoy the sights!

Comment: That seems like a possible match. Given there is no train assigned to the itinerary, would there still be a *matching* train or any train shortly after would be possible? No matter how long I look at this timetable, I don't understand how to read it. The only 721 there seems to run at a completely different time and none of the times seem to match exactly. Is there a way to validate the connection?

Comment: @Itai that timetable is of 2018, the updated one seems to be https://camel3.com/cms/files/izukyu/MASTER/1340/zNH1wm3s.pdf. It has a 721 departing at 11:27, like your schedule. After that I guess your booking website doesn't specify a particular train because it's for the regular JR trains with unreserved seats, so you could sit on any of them. The Saphir-Odoriko mentioned in the other answer only has reserved seats - for that train, on top of your current booking IIRC you'd need to get a seat reservation and a limited express ticket. I'd bet your booking includes the base fare till Ito.

Comment: @muru How did you determine the date of the timetable?  And how did you find the your version?  I know my version wasn't an exact match given the slight discrepancy in times compared to the OPs ticket (which is why I started with "I think")

Comment: @PeterM the filename of the one you linked is "outbound_e20181001" (also PDF properties say modification date "9/26/2018, 2:01:23 PM). The one I linked to is from https://www.izukyu.co.jp/global_site/ (section "Timetable > Outbound(For Izukyu-Shimoda Area)"